# C++: How call a function with type parameter on variadic template arguments?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

So I have a function with variadic template arguments and I'm trying to invoke a method (with a type parameter) for every argument, pack every result value in a `std::tuple` and return it. However variadic templates are pretty hard for me and I haven't fully understood them yet.

Is it even possible to realize this in C++?

Here's my code so far (which has an error in the `getMultiple` function). Thank you very much for helping!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

template<typename T>
T get(std::istream &stream) {
    T data;
    stream >> data;
    return data;
}

template<typename ... Ts>
std::tuple<Ts...> getMultiple(std::istream &stream) {
    // What am I doing wrong here?
    return std::make_tuple((get<Ts...>(stream)));
}

int main() {
    std::istringstream stream("count 2");
    auto [command, number] = getMultiple<std::string, int>(stream);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you forgot the

```
#include <tuple>
```

And the syntax you're probably looking for is:

```
return std::make_tuple(get<Ts>(stream)...);
```

Comment: This isn't quite right: the calls to `get` are indeterminately sequenced. You should get rid of `make_tuple` and just call the constructor with `return {get<Ts>(stream)...};`

Answer (score 3):

You are nearly correct, but your `...` are misplaced,

`get<Ts...>(stream)` translates to `get<T0, T1, .., Tn>(stream)`

it would be

`foo(get<Ts>(stream)...)` which translate to `foo(get<T0>(stream), get<T1>(stream), .., get<Tn>(stream))`

and you have issue with evaluation order

in `foo(a(), b())`, `a()` and `b()` are indeterminately sequenced, so `a()` might happens before `b()`, or the reverse. variadic template doesn't change that.

So you cannot use `std::make_tuple`. Fortunately inside `{..}`, order is determined from left to right, so you might use:

`return std::tuple{get<Ts>(stream)...};`

Comment: I would not write `std::tuple` in the `return`. We already know the exact type of the return from the function declaration, so just `return {get<Ts>(stream)...};` would work. That way we don't have to worry about class template argument deduction getting the types correct.

Comment: @HTNW I agree that it's redundant, but why would there be any issues with CTAD getting the types correct?

Comment: @cigien Consider the simplification `template<typename... T> std::tuple<T...> do_something() { return std::tuple{T()...}; }`, and then the call `do_something<std::tuple<int, int>>()`. Do you immediately see how this works? A `std::tuple<int, int>` is default-constructed. The written `std::tuple` deduces to `std::tuple<int, int>` too, choosing copy-construction. Then the return value is constructed (with the "direct constructor") with this as its sole element. Why introduce all those hidden steps when you can write `{Ts()...}` and make it immediately clear that it will work?